# how to generate datepicker bootstrap datesDisabled dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

i am trying to generate dynamically the disabled dates using ajax call , and pass the result to datesDisabled option of bootstrap datepicker , or for other alternative pass the result to beforeShowDay option , but it doesn't work for dynamically created array Result, but it worked fine for hard coded array.

In fact , when i use dynamically generated Array , the Date Array is passed to beforeShowDay in the second time i choose dates from datepicker, and it is not passed to the picker in the first time,
but when hard coded, the array is perfectly passed to beforShowDay from the first time the picker is clicked.

the dynamically created array is
Date Array:

```
2021-03-17,2021-03-18,2021-03-24,2021-04-06,2021-04-07,2021-04-13,2021-04-14
```

so what am doing wrong?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    function GetHolidayOrStopDay() {
      // alert("Get Holidays");
      var DateArray = new Array();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "timeObjectWebService.asmx/GetHolidaysAndDisabledDays",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
          var JsonObject = JSON.parse(data.d);

          $(JsonObject).each(function (index, da) {
            var testJsonDate = formatJsonDate(da.HolidayDate);
            var options = {
              year: "numeric",
              month: "numeric",
              day: "numeric",
            };
            var result = testJsonDate.toLocaleDateString("en", options);
            result = new Date(result);
            var DateResult = formatDate(result);
            //if (index < (JsonObject.length - 1)) {

            DateArray.push(DateResult);
            // }
            // else {
            //    DateArray += DateResult;
            //}
            console.log("rrr : " + DateResult);
          });
          //DateArray += ']';
          console.log("Date Array :" + DateArray);
          //console.log("1 : " + DateArray[1]);
        },
        error: function (err) {
          //alert("test err");
          console.log(err);
        },
      });
      //alert(DateArray);
      TestdisabledDays = DateArray;
      return DateArray;
    }

    function formatJsonDate(jsonDate) {
      var dat = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
      return dat;
    }

    var enableDays = ["2021-03-30"];
    var disabledDays = [
      "2021-03-23",
      "2021-03-22",
      "2021-03-30",
      "2021-03-29",
      "2021-03-28",
      "2021-04-01",
    ]; //for this hardcoded array everything works fine
    var TestdisabledDays = new Array();
    TestdisabledDays = GetHolidayOrStopDay();
    //GetHolidayOrStopDay();
    function formatDate(d) {
      var day = String(d.getDate());
      //add leading zero if day is is single digit

      if (day.length == 1) day = "0" + day;
      var month = String(d.getMonth() + 1);
      //add leading zero if month is is single digit
      if (month.length == 1) month = "0" + month;
      return d.getFullYear() + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    }

    $("#dtpicker").datepicker({
      format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
      autoclose: true,
      startDate: "0d",
      datesDisabled: [TestdisabledDays],

      beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        //alert("from picker");
        //for disable weekends :
        var dayNr = date.getDay();
        if (dayNr == 0 || dayNr == 6) {
          if (enableDays.indexOf(formatDate(date)) >= 0) {
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        }

        if (TestdisabledDays.indexOf(formatDate(date)) >= 0) {
          console.log("index of " + TestdisabledDays.indexOf(formatDate(date))); //disabledDays
          console.log("TestdisabledDays = " + TestdisabledDays); //disabledDays
          return false;
        }

        return true;
      },
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

ajax and datepicker init are running asychronically the picker is initializing before the ajax is done(that's why it is working second time), to solve this you might consider using $.when (api.jquery.com/jquery.when) or init the datepicker then when ajax return response use the methods of the datepicker itself (bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/.../methods...) hope this helps